# Estimating a combinatorial summation regarding multinomial distribution

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, multinomial-coefficients

We know that for $\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i=1, \forall i, p_i\ge0$, since $(\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i)^m=1, m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, we have multinomial equation $$\sum_{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_K=m}\frac{m!}{m_1!m_2!\dots m_K!}\prod_i p_i^{m_i}=1$$.

What can we say about the following quantity
$$\sum_{m_1+m_2+\dots+m_K=m}\frac{(Bm)!}{(Bm_1)!(Bm_2)!\dots (Bm_K)!}\prod_i p_i^{Bm_i}$$
for $B\in\mathbb{N}^+$? For example, its asymptotic lower bound/upper bound in terms of $B, K, p, M$, or even its closed-form.

Comment: By the roots of unity filter this is $B^{-K}\sum (p_1w_1+\ldots +p_Kw_K)^{Bm}$, where $w_j$ runs over roots of unity of degree $B$ for all $j=1, \ldots, k$.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate more about the roots of unity filter? Thanks.

Comment: See theorem 1 here http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Multi-GF_A06_MathRefl.pdf